# How to paint tasks with different colors in Gantt chart based on some user defined criteria in Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex

I was wondering is it possible to paint tasks with different colors in a Gantt chart based on some criteria in Oracle APEX? I read tasks from 2 different tables combined with union in the query, and was wondering if i can paint them based on the table they are read from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can!

You can leverage any or all of the three attribute fields here for managing the CSS styling of the tasks.

[image]

If you check the help for these fields, the help mentions the following:

> Enter CSS classes to be applied to baseline bars on the Gantt chart. You may add multiple classes by separating them with spaces. You can utilize &COLUMN_VALUE. substitutions.

So instead of hard-coding it, you can **use a column** you can add to your query with your logic with a `case-when` clause. For example:

```sql
SELECT ..., 
  CASE 
    when criteria_column = 'value1' then 'u-color-22' 
    when criteria_column = 'value2' then 'u-color-23'
    when criteria_column = 'value3' then 'u-color-24'
    else 'u-color-25'
  END AS task_color
from my_union
```

Comment: https://diveintoapex.com/tag/gantt/ I was lucky to stumble upon this article and managed to make it work...